# Receive full data

Tags: c#, exception, networking, tcplistener, networkstream

I wrote a small program that receives a huge string over TCP.

I am able to read from the network stream only one time and then the program crashes. How can I fix this problem or can you suggest me a better way to send big string over TCP. The client's buffer size is 202601176 (The string bytes length).

This is my code:

```
namespace File_Transfer_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6666);
            serverListener.Start();
            TcpClient tcpClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(">>> Receiving");

            byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[1024];
            Console.WriteLine(clientBuffer.Length);
            using (NetworkStream clientNStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {

                int i;
                string received = "";

                while ((i = clientNStream.Read(clientBuffer, 0, clientBuffer.Length)) > 0) //exception
                {
                    string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientBuffer, 0, i);
                    received += data;
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                }
                File.WriteAllText(@"E:\receivedData.txt", received);
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at File_Transfer_Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Files from PC\Visual Basic Projects - =&+Ivan+&=\Tesseract\Temp\File Transfer\File_Transfer_Server\Program.cs:line 29
```

**EDIT:**

Client code:

```
namespace File_Transfer_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6666);

            NetworkStream clientNetworkStream = client.GetStream();

            string fileContent = FileBase64Encoding(@"D:\Download\AtomSetup-x64.exe");

                        byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent);
            // byte[] fileLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileBytes.Length.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(fileBytes.Length);
            clientNetworkStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Send");
        }

        static string FileBase64Encoding(string path)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            string fileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

            return fileBase64String;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the client code that sends string? I have no problem receiving all the data using your code

Comment: @BART Done! BTW, the base64 encoding is part of the assignment.

Comment: Cool. What you may want to do is implement some kind of message framing mechanism. e.g. Write the string length (e.g. 4 byte integer) before string contents. Also there is always advantage of splitting up the message into smaller chunks. I shall test your code and get back to you with some examples for your particular case. Meanwhile you may want to read this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is the client closes connection before the server manages to receive all the data. You have to tell the server about the length of your message. This is called "Message Framing".

## **Solution**

1. Write the length of the message before it's content and read it at the server end.
2. Allocate the buffer at the server with the size of message length.
3. Read message contents.

Optional step: To make sure we won't have any Socket exceptions Make the client wait for the server until it receives all the data. Server closes the connection.

**Client code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6666);

    NetworkStream clientNetworkStream = client.GetStream();

    string fileContent = FileBase64Encoding(@"D:\Download\AtomSetup-x64.exe");

    byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent);
    // byte[] fileLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileBytes.Length.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(fileBytes.Length);

    // Write the length of a message
    var integerBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileBytes.Length); // integer has 4 bytes
    clientNetworkStream.Write(integerBytes, 0, integerBytes.Length);

    // Write the contents
    clientNetworkStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Send");

    // Wait for server to finish receiving
    clientNetworkStream.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
}

static string FileBase64Encoding(string path)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string fileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

    return fileBase64String;
}
```

**Server code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6666);
        serverListener.Start();
        TcpClient tcpClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(">>> Receiving");

        byte[] clientBuffer;
        using (NetworkStream clientNStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        {

            int i;
            string received = "";

            byte[] integerBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            clientNStream.Read(integerBytes, 0, integerBytes.Length); // receive message length
            int messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(integerBytes, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Received message length: {0}", messageLength);

            clientBuffer = new byte[messageLength]; // allocate buffer

            clientNStream.Read(clientBuffer, 0, clientBuffer.Length); // read string contents

            Console.WriteLine("Received all the data");

            // we're done
            Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
            tcpClient.Close();

            received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientBuffer, 0, clientBuffer.Length);

            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\receivedData.txt", received);
            Console.WriteLine(">>>Done");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code for the server now is simpler.

Ideally you would want some more advanced message framing mechanism that can split your message into much smaller chunks and write directly to a file, because you will run out of memory for really big files and is always good idea to split big messages into smaller chunks.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will try it later, only one last question - what if I don't want to close connection, is it okay to keep the tcp client on the server open?

Comment: It's perfectly fine if you have a reason to. You can keep connection open until you're done with the client or client is done with the server. The issue is Network Programming is a tricky one, so I can't give you 'yes' or 'no' answer without knowing your scenario, but many clients keep their connection open for long time e.g. I work for the company where vehicles/cars are connected to the server all day long and exchanging data constantly

Comment: I've used the method again in another project of mine, but when I send a default message after using this I don't get the first byte. Everything works fine if I remove the netStream.ReadByte(); line of code. Is this line necessary? I think that there is something to do with it returning -1 when the stream ends. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, can I use the same method to send large files, not strings(.png/.exe and e.g.)?

Comment: @IvanZlatanov `clientNetworkStream.ReadByte();` is there just for client to wait until server receives all the data. It's not really necessary. If you can share link to your current code for the server and client somwhere here in the comment section I can take a look at it. And yes you can send png/exe/whatever files with this method, just don't convert them to base64 string if you don't want to - read and send just as raw bytes